# How can I send an sms from my mobile to my PC?

Tags: java, sms

how to send SMS from mobile to PC without using blue-tooth, data-cable?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for sounding a bit simple, but what about an email address? You could listen for new emails, and even perform conditional logic based upon what the email contains.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToReceiveSMSUsingPC.asp:

> In general, there are three ways to
>   receive SMS messages using your
>   computer / PC:
>
> 1. Connect a mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem to a computer / PC. Then use the
>      computer / PC and AT commands to get
>      the received SMS messages from the
>      mobile phone or GSM/GPRS modem.
> 2. Get access to the SMS center (SMSC) or SMS gateway of a wireless carrier.
>      Any SMS messages received will be
>      forwarded to your computer / PC using
>      a protocol / interface supported by
>      the SMSC or SMS gateway.
> 3. Get access to the SMS gateway of an SMS service provider. Any SMS messages
>      received will be forwarded to your
>      computer / PC using a protocol /
>      interface supported by the SMS
>      gateway.
>
> If you do not want to develop SMS
>   software or applications but just want
>   to use your computer / PC to receive
>   text messages, you may want to read
>   [our Quick Guide for
>   Non-Developers.](http://www.developershome.com/sms/#quickGuideNonDevelopers)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Kannel: Open Source WAP and SMS Gateway](http://www.kannel.org/).

I successfully configured it once, by attaching a mobile phone to my computer. After a successful testing we opted for subscribing to SMS service provider. In the latter case the service provider used to invoke our URL in order to deliver received SMS.

Comment: how to do it practically? any helpful coding or configurations?